# Can anyone tell me why my sorting doesn't work? (c code)

Tags: c, sorting

I just started programming.
I just wrote this code and it does not work.
Can you please tell me why?

code =

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j;
    int s;

    printf("enter 10 numbers: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f, &g, &h, &i, &j);

    int numbers[10] = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j};

    //%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d        a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j
    printf("before \n %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j);

    for (int k = 0; k == 10; k++) {
        if (numbers[k] <= numbers[k + 1]) {
            numbers[k] = s;
            numbers[k] = numbers[k + 1];
            numbers[k + 1] = s;

        }
    }

    printf("after \n %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4], numbers[5], numbers[6], numbers[7], numbers[8], numbers[9]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is direct violation of how to ask questions rules))

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? What is not working? What error do you get when you try to run your code? Once you tell that in your post then you can except some help from the community.

Comment: 1. Turn up your compiler warnings. That will expose at least one of your issues. 2. Run your code in a debugger, single stepping and examining variable values to trace what is happening in your code. That will expose at least one more issue.

Comment: first, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, I'm pretty sure the input to your scanf function is wrong. The first '%d' is going to munch all of the digits in the string, so variables b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, and j will be uninitialized.

Also, you're doing `numbers[k] = s;` and `numbers[k + 1] = s;` when 's' hasn't been initialized to anything.

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors in the above code. First of all , your "for" condition is wrong (k==10). Secondly, traversing the array only once is not sufficient. You need to traverse your array as many times until no swap needs to take place. (see Bubblesort)

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop condition becomes falls at first instance, at first step k is 0 and its check for value 10 `(if (k==10) in (k=0;k==10;k++))` This will not going to execute your for loop logic and at first case you come out from for loop.

Answer (score 0):

To help you see what could be wrong with your sorting code

In English/Pseudo-Code :

```
Read 10 elements of the array
For each 11 elements ( 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ) of the array 
    if the current element is less of equals to the next element ( including the 12th element when the element index is 11 )
        then
            Store the value in 's' in place of the current element ( what is in 's' might be up to the phase of the moon )
            Store the value of the next element in the current element ( we will never know what was the the mystery value in 's', unless .... )
            Store the value of 's' in the next element ( next comparison will be a big surprise )


Print the 10 elements of the transformed array
```

To be fair it's might still not be enough to show your mistakes

let's have a card analogy

- shuffle your deck of 52 cards
- pick 10 cards from the deck ( 7 10 5 4 ... )
- look at the first card of your hand ( for example a 7 of Diamond )
- look at the next one ( for example a 10 of Club )
- if the first one is lesser or equal to the second one then :

  - replace the first card by the top card of the deck ( example : queen of Heart )
  - throw away the first card
  - replace the new card by the second card
  - put the new card at the second place
- look a the second card ( queen of Heart )
- look at the third card ( 5 of Spade )
  ... Let's skip to the 10th card
- look at the 10th card ( ok .... )
- look at the 11th card ( you warp the dimension to see another card in the 55th dimension, it is an XZ of Roses )
- Compare the values ( by applying multidimensional mathematics, you find out that Shrodinger's cat is alive and kicking )
- The sun is coming closer to the earth causing some strange Ice Age that would last for a second
  ...
- Those whose name no one should speak bring you a 12th card
  ...
- you have been eaten by a grue

Other than trying to look for values that doesn't exist, some people have advised you to look at [simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Implementation) [sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementation) [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm_for_insertion_sort) that provide some easy to understand pseudo-code

Good luck in you journey in learning C